# ESP 8266 HTTP Client Data is not changing correctly

Tags: esp8266

I'm Trying to control a pin "D1" from HTTP API everything was working fine but when i'm going to change the data from server it's done on the server but on device it's takes so long time almost 20 minutes i also checked the Serial Monitor the data is not updating please help me.

My Device: Node MCU V3,

Here is my code:

```
/**
   BasicHTTPClient.ino

    Created on: 24.05.2015

*/

#include <Arduino.h>

#include <Arduino_JSON.h>

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>

#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

#include <WiFiClient.h>

ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Serial.setDebugOutput(true);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();

  pinMode(D1, OUTPUT);

  for (uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
    Serial.printf("[SETUP] WAIT %d...\n", t);
    Serial.flush();
    delay(1000);
  }

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFiMulti.addAP("Maruf Hasan", "marufhasan");

}

void loop() {
  // wait for WiFi connection
  if ((WiFiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED)) {

    WiFiClient client;

    HTTPClient http;

    Serial.print("[HTTP] begin...\n");
    if (http.begin(client, "http://marufhasan.net/api/test.txt")) {  // HTTP


      Serial.print("[HTTP] GET...\n");
      // start connection and send HTTP header
      int httpCode = http.GET();

      // httpCode will be negative on error
      if (httpCode > 0) {
        // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
        Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);

        // file found at server
        if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK || httpCode == HTTP_CODE_MOVED_PERMANENTLY) {
          String response = http.getString();
          //Converting response object;
          Serial.println(response);
          JSONVar myObject = JSON.parse(response);

          if (JSON.typeof(myObject) == "undefined") {
            Serial.println("Parsing input failed!");
          }else{
            if (myObject.hasOwnProperty("status")) {
              String status = (const char*) myObject["status"];


              if(status=="on"){
                    Serial.println("ON");
                    digitalWrite(D1, HIGH);
              }else{
                    Serial.println("OFF");
                    digitalWrite(D1, LOW);
              }

            }  
          }          
        }
      } else {
        Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
      }

      http.end();
    } else {
      Serial.printf("[HTTP} Unable to connect\n");
    }
  }

  delay(5000);
}
```

Comment: Your server has a cache control of 10-min. `Cache-Control: max-age=600`.